# In Safari, and only if I open devtools, I get TypeError: Module specifier: does not start with "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: safari, es6-modules

This issue does not happen with Chrome. Note again that the page only fails with this error if devtools is open. The software works, but I am not able to test or debug it with Safari. This is a problem because I will not be able to look into any Safari-specific issues.

The page is based off of a three.js example page. Here is how the HTML is set up:

```
    <!-- Import maps polyfill -->
    <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/build/three.module.js"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module" src="v2.js"></script>
```

The error is:

```
[Error] TypeError: Module specifier, 'three' does not start with "/", "./", or "../". Referenced from http://localhost:8000/v2.js
promiseReactionJob
```

Comment: I understand the downvote, this kind of looks like a low effort question... but I'm unfamiliar with the new esm approach and the error does not give me any line number in safari and no other browser is complaining. Would be great if someone could point me towards maybe a "loading ESM in browsers in 2022" article at least.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I am having exactly the same issue and googled the whole internet with no results at all. Tried everything now, I am lost.

Comment: @LubWn I noticed (maybe this is new with a more recent version of es-module-shims.min.js?) it produces the console log `^^ Module TypeError above is polyfilled and can be ignored ^^` to help reassure you that this is just a side effect of the polyfill. I also noticed chrome does not spit this error out for me anymore (at least on Linux here).

Comment: I fixed it by downgrading threejs to v127, which was the last version before they switched imports to importmap (which is the cause of all this and is unsupported by firefox / safari). So now it works on iphones as well. So maybe this would help you as well, just downgrade the threejs and abandon importmap in general.

Comment: The import map thing works fine on every browser. it's just that some browsers produce the error and others don't but I have not seen any that don't work. Are you sure it actually even breaks your app?

Comment: I realized that the original problem I was posting about (not able to use safari devtools) mysteriously stopped being a problem for me because i use safari devtools on this app all the time these days.

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure. It was importmap, it does not work on safari and firefox at all, yielding the same error as you have.

Comment: The error does not stop it from working for me though. I cannot reproduce the problem stated in my question actually.

Answer (score 1):

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/import-maps) Safari doesn't even support import maps. This software actually works however, so the rabbit hole goes deeper.

I've also got Firefox installed now. It's got the same behavior as shown by Safari, but there is no brokenness if devtools is open. Based on [this topic](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/23760), an esm loader polyfill is in play. I believe it might be this: https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims

Comment: This works https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims